# vhdl case...is and with...select

Tags: select, case, vhdl

I'm trying to write something on VHDL, but it's not working. Here's part of my code:

```
case currentState is
    when ST000 =>
        with A select nextState <=
            ST025 when "01",
            ST050 when "10",
            ST000 when "11",
            currentState when others;
    when ST001 => ...
    when others => ...
end case;
```

It says there's a problem in these lines, like this: `Line 62. parse error, unexpected WITH`. Why is this `with` unexpected? Is it wrong to mix these two syntaxes, `case...is` and `with...select`, together?

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimal complete verifiable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise notes, reference are from IEEE Std 1076-2008, IEEE VHDL Language Reference Manual.

> **10. Sequential statements**
>
> **10.1 General**
>
> The various forms of sequential statements are described in this clause. Sequential statements are used to define algorithms for the execution of a subprogram or process; they execute in the order in which they appear.
>
> **10.9 Case statement**
>
> A case statement selects for execution one of a number of alternative sequences of statements; the chosen alternative is defined by the value of an expression.

A sequence of statements indicates sequential statements.

> **10.5.4 Selected signal assignments**
>
> The selected signal assignment represents an equivalent case statement that assigns values to signals or that forces or releases signals.

However...

> **Annex E**
>   (informative)
>   **Changes from IEEE Std 1076-2002**
>
> ...
>   **Clause 10**
>
> > — 10.5: Addition of force and release assignment; addition of simple, conditional and selected signal assignment.

In revisions of the VHDL standard earlier than -2008 selected signal assignments were only available as concurrent signal assignment statements (See 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements, or found in Clause/Chapter 9 Concurrent Statements, subsection 9.5.2 Selected signal assignment in earlier revisions of the VHDL standard).

Note that when inconvenient or lacking support for this -2008 feature you can substitute a case statement:

```
case currentState is
    when ST000 =>
        case A is
            when "01" =>
                nextState <= ST025;
            when "10" =>
                nextState <= ST050;
            when "11" =>
                nextState <= ST000;
            when others =>
                nextState <= CurrentState;
        end case;
    when ST001 => ...
    when others => ...
end case;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I saw that it worked if I put `case` instead of signal `select`, but didn't really understand why.