# With select statement

Tags: vhdl, with-statement

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```

---

```
ENTITY sevenOut4Decoder is


PORT (
  input   : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0); --! 4-bit binary input
  display : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 TO 7)      --! 7-signals to control led display
);

END ENTITY Deco;
```

---

```
ARCHITECTURE implementation OF Deco IS
  


BEGIN


  process(display,input)
  begin
  with input select display <= 
     '0010001' when '0001', --A
     '0000000' when '0010', --B
     '1100010' when '0011', --C
     '0000101' when '0100', --D
     '1100000' when '0101', --E
     '1110000' when '0111', --F
     '1000000' when '1000', --G
     '1111111' when others;
   end process;
  
  



END ARCHITECTURE implementation;
```

Dear readers i have the following problem,
everytime i try to run this code i get the following error message:

Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Deco.vhd(171) near text "with";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement

now correct me if im wrong but after with statement comes a identifier called input why does it keep giving me this error? does it have something to do with the proces?

Thanks in advance im new to VHDL and have a lot to learn

Comment: `With-select` can only be used inside a process with VHDL 2008

Comment: It's not a with-statement. It's a selected signal assignment. Besides requiring -2008 there are other errors in the OP's code. The entity name doesn't match in either it's end statement or the architecture declaration. The right bound of the declaration of display should be 6 (0 identity) to get 7 elements. The process doesn't evaluate display, it's not needed in the process sensitivity list. String literals are bound by double quotes and not single quotes. A selected signal assignment statement has a case statement equivalent or it can be moved out of the process if not using -2008.

Comment: Possible duplicate. See [vhdl case...is and with...select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067025/vhdl-case-is-and-with-select/).

Answer (score 0):

With-select can only be used inside a process with VHDL 2008

Besides requiring -2008 there are other errors in the code. The entity name doesn't match in either it's end statement or the architecture declaration. The right bound of the declaration of display should be 6 (0 identity) to get 7 elements. The process doesn't evaluate display, it's not needed in the process sensitivity list. String literals are bound by double quotes and not single quotes. A selected signal assignment statement has a case statement equivalent or it can be moved out of the process if not using -2008.

Comment: If you'd only put effort into research instead of copying comments (possible duplicate). There's also the issue of question quality given the lack of a [mcve] and string literal syntax errors. See [answer], **Answer well-asked questions**. Answering low quality questions showing no research effort encourages more questions of similar quality. For those dependent on  edit queue availability suggesting changes to improve the quality of the original post can often only be done in comments or otherwise held captive to review queue user moderation quality.